# permutations of string in ascending order

Tags: c++, c, permutation

Write a program to form permutations of strings by taking as follows:
Input: `ABCD`
Output:

```
A
AB
AC
AD
ABC
ACD
ABCD
B
BC
BD
BCD
C
CD
D
```

But I Tried using back tracking algorithm in c language:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* Function to swap values at two pointers */
void swap(char *x, char *y)
{
    char temp;
    temp = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = temp;
}

void permute(char *a, int i, int n)
{
    int j;
    if(i == n)
        printf("%s\n", a);
    else
    {
        for(j = i; j <= n; j++)
        {
            swap((a + i), (a + j));
            permute(a, i + 1, n);
            swap((a + i), (a + j)); //backtrack
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    char a[] = "ABC";
    permute(a, 0, 2);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Input: `ABC`

Output:

```
ABC
ACB
BAC
BCA
CBA
CAB
```

But I need a program for only specified order like

```
A
AB
AC
ABC
B
BC
C
```

Comment: What has this got to do with [tag:java]?

Comment: What is your specific question? And "fix my program" is not a question.

Comment: it sounds like your a bad teacher telling us to write a program that you failed to write yourself but your probably a student who can't ask a decent question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example the strings are not in ascending order: you have AB, AC, AD, ABC, ..., but then you have B, BC before C, and D. If you want it in alphabetical order should be A, AB, ABC, ABCD, AC, ....

When you write it that way you see the recursive structure ... just take the A off the first half of the list and you should get the second. So you can easily write a recursive program that does something like

```
permute("ABCD"):
  print ("A" + everything in permute("BCD"))
  print (everything in permute("BCD"))
```